# router navigation link is created successfully but component is not rendered in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

In Angular 8, I am using click function to run a custom function onView(row) and then try to redirect towards the child route by using this.router.navigate(['show/', row.id], { relativeTo: this.route }), but when I click then URL changes http://localhost:4200/#/customers/show/1 but this route component (CustomerEditComponent) is not loaded and webpage still showing the CustomersComponent content rather than to show the (CustomerEditComponent). Could you please help me with how I can load the HTML of CustomerEditComponent?.

```
onView(row){
   this.router.navigate(['show/' , row.id], { relativeTo: this.route }).then( (e) => {
      if (e) {
        console.log("Navigation is successful!");
      } else {
        console.log("Navigation has failed!");
      }
    });
  }

customers-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomersComponent } from "./customers.component";
import { CustomerEditComponent } from "./customer-edit/customer-edit.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomersComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'customers', pathMatch: 'full' },
        {
          path: 'show/:id',
          component: CustomerEditComponent,
          data: {
            title: 'Customer'
          }
        }
      ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class CustomersRoutingModule { }

admin-layout.routing.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerEditComponent } from "../../../pages/admin/customers/customer-edit/customer-edit.component";

const adminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'customers',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
    },

    {
        path: 'contacts',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/contacts/contacts.module').then(m => m.ContactsModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'administrators',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/administrators/administrators.module').then(m => m.AdministratorsModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'orders',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'institutions',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/institutions/institutions.module').then(m => m.InstitutionsModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'service-desk',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../pages/admin/service-desk/service-desk.module').then(m => m.ServiceDeskModule)
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(adminLayoutRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AdminLayoutRoutingModule { }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPzoe.png

app.routing.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {
  AuthGuardService as AuthGuard,
  UnauthGuardService as UnauthGuard,
  AdminLayoutComponent
} from './core';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./core/layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module').then(m => m.AdminLayoutModule)
      }
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }, {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
    canActivate: [UnauthGuard]
  }, {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: does it work if you manually type in the url ? also, try to set enableTracing to true for router config, that might give you some insight of what's happening

Comment: Have you forget to add a router-outlet directive in the template of any parent component?

Comment: If I manually type in the URL, then it still shows the parent component, not a child. router-outlet directive is already added in the parent component HTML file in the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared your `CustomerEditComponent` route as one of `CustomerComponent` children routes, so `Angular` will try to render `CustomerEditComponent` inside your `CustomerComponent` where `router-outlet` is. If you have not `router-outlet` inside `CustomerComponent` it will not render `CustmoerEditComponent`.

Also, this one looks kinda weird: 
`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'customers', pathMatch: 'full' },`. Why you need that? You should put some `route` which will redirect you to your url with `CustomerComponent` outside of `CustomerComponent` children routes.

Comment: I am already declared <router-outlet></router-outlet> in customer.component.html file in the last. But still facing the same issue

Comment: Put your project on github and share link to repository.

Comment: This is a repository link in the GitHub, please let me know if you need anything else

https://github.com/albert-edward/angular-project